# Overriding getView() in CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, garbage-collection, android-cursoradapter

I just wanted to know that can we override the `getView()` method in a class that extends the `CursorAdapter` class?The unimplemented method in the `CursorAdapter` class are `newView()` to inflate a `View` and `bindView()` to bind the data from the data source to the `View`.But the problem is that we cannot save the `View` inside the `newView()` method and therefore it runs `garbage collection` more often as compared to `getView()` where we get a previous instance of the `View` create earlier.So can we override `getView()` instead of `newView()` in the class that extends `CursorAdapter`? And if we can,do we need to call it ourselves every time or would the compiler would do it for us?
Code is added
I am trying to make a music player and i have made a single class to handle the adapter.I have specified the type of each class and have made an object of this custom adapter class to handle view inflation and data binding.

```
public class PopulatingListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private final static int ALL_SONGS_TYPE = 0;
private final static int ALBUM_SONGS = 1;
private final static int ARTIST_SONGS = 2;
private final static int ALBUM_TYPE = 3;
private final static int ARTIST_TYPE = 4;

private final LayoutInflater myInflater;

private int typeOfList;

public void setType(int type){
    typeOfList=type;
}

public PopulatingListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(typeOfList==ALL_SONGS_TYPE)
    {   
        TextView songTitleNameAllSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.all_song_title);
        songTitleNameAllSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));

        TextView songDisplayNameAllSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.all_song_display);
        songDisplayNameAllSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        ImageView albumArtInAllSongs = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_art_all_songs_single_row);

    }else if(typeOfList==ALBUM_TYPE)
    {   
        TextView albumCoverTitleInAllAlbums = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_cover_title);
        albumCoverTitleInAllAlbums.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));

        TextView artistAlbumTitleInAllAlbums = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_album_title);
        artistAlbumTitleInAllAlbums.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST)));

        ImageView albumArtInAllAlbum = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_single_row_album_art);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART)));
        if(bmp!=null)
            albumArtInAllAlbum.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        else
            albumArtInAllAlbum.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.head_10));        
    }else if(typeOfList==ARTIST_TYPE)
    {   
        TextView artistNameInAllArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artists_single_name);
        artistNameInAllArtist.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST)));

    }else if(typeOfList==ALBUM_SONGS)
    {   
        TextView albumSongTitleNameInAlbumSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.albums_songs_name_of_song);
        albumSongTitleNameInAlbumSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));

        TextView albumSongDisplayNameInAlbumSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.albums_songs_name_of_album);
        albumSongDisplayNameInAlbumSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));
    }else if(typeOfList==ARTIST_SONGS){
        TextView artistSongTitleNameInArtistSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_song_title_name);
        artistSongTitleNameInArtistSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));

        TextView artistSongDisplayNameInArtistSongs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_song_artist_name);
        artistSongDisplayNameInArtistSongs.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)));
    }
  }


/*@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}*/

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View myView=null;
        if(typeOfList==ALL_SONGS_TYPE)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.all_songs_single_row, parent, false);
        }else if(typeOfList==ALBUM_TYPE)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.album_single_row, parent, false);
        }else if(typeOfList==ARTIST_TYPE)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.artists_single_row, parent, false);
        }else if(typeOfList==ALBUM_SONGS)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.albums_songs_single_row, parent, false);
        }else if(typeOfList==ARTIST_SONGS)
        {
            myView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.artists_song_single_row, parent, false);
        }
    return myView;
}
```

}

Comment: use bindview. the view recycling is already handled for you. bindview parameter is an inflated or recycled view which is always valid for you to use.

Comment: there is no reason why getview would be more efficient. post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can override it. Here's how:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

}
```

**That being said**, you don't have (don't need) to. `newView` and `bindView` is called by `getView`. So overriding `getView` would basically change nothing.

You simply create the views yourself and bind the data, without having a headache of working with the `convertViews`.

All the caching is done in the background, that is if you didn't override the `getView` method.

You can find the source code for most android classes pretty easily. Here's [`CursorAdapter`'s `getView` method implementation.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Actually i ran the code with a logcat and it shows every new view being created when i scrolled up or down and that reduced the performance of my list a lot....So it wasn't efficient Garbage Collection.....And we need to return views both from getView() and newView()...So i just want to asked that which should we work with....or do we need to return views from both?

Comment: @L_Lawliet try the logcat+scroll method again and make sure getView is not overridden. I'd like to see the output of that.

Comment: @L_Lawliet okay, I see you've posted your code now. You have multiple item layouts s it's pretty normal for the `newView` to be called multiple times, even when scrolling.

Comment: @L_Lawliet if `getView` is not overridden you can be sure it caches the views. The problem seems to be not in the way you call your methods but in the item layouts themselves. There may be too many, or they may be too complex to be quickly rendered by the android system.

Comment: They are just basic layouts and each of them contains just two TextView and a small ImageView.....so should i make separate class for each of the adapters? or is there some other solution too?

Comment: @L_Lawliet if the layouts are identical, I don't see why you would separate them. This is what causes the lag. It also seems to be off-topic to the question you asked.

Comment: Just wanted to avoid clustering.....so reducing the type of layout would reduce the lag?

Comment: @L_Lawliet yes, greatly. Because for each type a new layout needs to be inflated until they're cached. Inflating is a performance-expensive operation.

Comment: ok....and i want to reduce another expensive operation i.e. referencing the variables every time a new view is created or the same view is scrolled through.....but the problem is that these views are referenced using the view passed in the bindView()....any ideas on that?

Comment: @L_Lawliet I'm not sure I understand. What variables? Do you mean the views you fetch with `findViewById`?

Comment: @L_Lawliet there's a way around that, and it's called the `ViewHolder` pattern. I don't want to get into much depth because it all has been answered multiple times. The best way to understand would be [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70).

Comment: Just wanted to ask one last thing.....how can we fetch data from multiple tables like MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI in a single loader....I want to load the song name and it's album art in the list of all songs but they won't run in the same loader as they are different tables.....any suggestion on that?

Comment: @L_Lawliet not sure, would need more information on that. And again it's off-topic for this question, so just open another one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple view types, you should override following from BaseAdapter to get the correct behavior:

- public int  getViewTypeCount ()
- public int  getItemViewType (int position)

Comment: i thought of using that but i don't know how to work an asynctask loader class with a base adapter that's why thought of using a loadermanager interface with a cursoradapter which i learnt from an example on the google dev site

Comment: I've been a bit to eager also. Looking at your code I don't think you're mixing multiple types of views at the same time, but probably just set the type with 'public void setType(int type)' and then execute your cursor

Comment: yes i am doing that exactly.....i am initiating only a single type of view at a single time.....

Comment: I am making an object of this class in different classes and passing a predefined type which i have set already in those classes and comparing them to the type that i have set in this class